# subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c, bucle-for, struct, float

Hacer 2 estructuras una llamada promedio que tendra los siguientes miembros: 
nota1,nota2,nota3; y otro llamada alumno que tendra los siguientes miembros:
nombre, sexo, edad; hacer que la estructura promedio este anidada en la estructura
alumno, luego pedir todos los datos para N alumnos, después calcular su promedio, imprimir todos sus datos incluidos el promedio y por ultimo, calcular el mejor promedio e imprimir los datos del alumno.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct promedio{
float nota1;
float nota2;
float nota3;
};

struct alumno{
char nombre[20];
char sexo[20];
int edad;
struct promedio prom;
}alumno1;

int main(){
float promedio=0,mayor=0,menor=999999;
int a,i,pmay,pmen;

printf("digite la cantidad de alumnos\n");
scanf("%i",&a);
for(i=0;i<a;i++){
    fflush(stdin);
printf("\n\nDigite su nombre: ");
gets(alumno1.nombre);
printf("Digite su sexo: ");
gets(alumno1.sexo);
printf("Digite su edad: ");
scanf("%i",&alumno1.edad);
printf("Digite las 3 notas: ");
scanf("%f %f %f",&alumno1.prom.nota1,&alumno1.prom.nota2,&alumno1.prom.nota3);

promedio = (alumno1.prom.nota1+alumno1.prom.nota2+alumno1.prom.nota3)/3;

printf("\n\n-Datos del Alumno-\n");
printf("\nNombre: %s",alumno1.nombre);
printf("\nSexo: %s",alumno1.sexo);
printf("\nEdad: %i",alumno1.edad);
printf("\nPromedio: %.2f\n\n",promedio);

fflush(stdin);

}
for(i=0;i<a;i++){
    if(alumno1[i].prom>mayor){
        mayor=alumno1[i].prom;
        pmay=i;
    }
    if(alumno1[i].prom<menor){
        menor=alumno1[i].prom;
        pmen=i;
    }


}
printf("\n\n\n-Datos del alumno con Mejor promedio\n");
printf("\nSu nombre es:%s\n",alumno1[pmay].nombre);
printf("\nSu promedio es:%i\n",alumno1[pmay].prom);
printf("\nSu edad es:%s\n",alumno1[pmay].edad);
printf("\nSu sexo es:%s\n",alumno1[pmay].sexo);*/




system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cual es el problema que tienes?

Comment: OT: para facilitar la legibilidad y la comprensión: sangra constantemente el código. Sangría después de cada llave de apertura '{'. Unindent antes de cada llave de cierre '}'. Sugiera que cada nivel de sangría sea de 4 espacios.

Comment: OT: la función: `gets ()` se ha depreciado durante años y se ha eliminado por completo del lenguaje C desde aproximadamente 2009. Sugiera usar `fgets ()` que tiene una lista de parámetros diferente, así que asegúrese de leer la página MAN

Comment: OT: Al compilar, siempre active las advertencias, luego corríjalas. (Para `gcc`, como mínimo, use las opciones:` -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std = gnu11`) Nota: otros compiladores usan diferentes opciones para producir los mismos resultados. Pasar el código publicado a través de una versión reciente de `gcc` da como resultado 7 advertencias y 5 mensajes de error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estabas tan lejos de lograrlo, solo tenias que declarar un array de tipo alumno y no una variable para que puedas ingresar mas de un alumno, también es necesario agregar el campo promedio a la estructura del alumno para que en él quede guardado el promedio de cada uno de ellos.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct notas{
    float nota1;
    float nota2;
    float nota3;
};

//redefinir estructura de notas como 'Notas'
typedef struct notas Notas;

struct alumno{
    char nombre[20];
    char sexo[20];
    int edad;
    float promedio; //agregando el campo promedio a la estructura es posible saber el promedio de cada uno de los alumnos y de esta forma encontrar el mayor de todos
    Notas notas;
};

//redefinir estructura de alumno como 'Alumno'
typedef struct alumno Alumno;

int main(void){
    int cantidad, i;
    float promMayor;

    printf("Indique cantidad de alumnos: ");
    scanf("%d",&cantidad);

    //array de tipo Alumno con longitud especificado por usuario
    Alumno alumnos[cantidad];

    printf("\n--- INGRESANDO ALUMNOS ---\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
        printf("Nombre: ");
        scanf("%s",alumnos[i].nombre);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Sexo  : ");
        scanf("%s",alumnos[i].sexo);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Edad  : ");
        scanf("%d",&alumnos[i].edad);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Nota1 : ");
        scanf("%f",&alumnos[i].notas.nota1);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Nota2 : ");
        scanf("%f",&alumnos[i].notas.nota2);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Nota3 : ");
        scanf("%f",&alumnos[i].notas.nota3);
        fflush(stdin);
        alumnos[i].promedio = (alumnos[i].notas.nota1+alumnos[i].notas.nota2+alumnos[i].notas.nota3)/3;
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("--- DATOS DE ALUMNOS ---\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
        printf("Alumno  : %s\n",alumnos[i].nombre);
        printf("Edad    : %d\n",alumnos[i].edad);
        printf("Sexo    : %s\n",alumnos[i].sexo);
        printf("Nota1   : %f\n",alumnos[i].notas.nota1);
        printf("Nota2   : %f\n",alumnos[i].notas.nota2);
        printf("Nota3   : %f\n",alumnos[i].notas.nota3);
        printf("Promedio: %f\n\n",alumnos[i].promedio);
    }

    //postular al primer alumno como el promedio mayor
    promMayor = alumnos[0].promedio;

    //luego comparar el promedio postulado con el promedio de todos los alumnos para encontrar el mayor
    for(i = 1; i < cantidad; i++){
        if(alumnos[i].promedio > promMayor){
            promMayor = alumnos[i].promedio;
        }
    }

    //mostrar aquellos alumnos cuyo promedio es igual al mayor encontrado
    printf("--- ALUMNOS CON PROMEDIO MAS ALTO ---\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
        if(alumnos[i].promedio == promMayor){
            printf("Alumno  : %s\n",alumnos[i].nombre);
            printf("Edad    : %d\n",alumnos[i].edad);
            printf("Sexo    : %s\n",alumnos[i].sexo);
            printf("Nota1   : %f\n",alumnos[i].notas.nota1);
            printf("Nota2   : %f\n",alumnos[i].notas.nota2);
            printf("Nota3   : %f\n",alumnos[i].notas.nota3);
            printf("Promedio: %f\n\n",alumnos[i].promedio);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Este no es válido: `Alumno alumnos[cantidad];`. Los [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) no son seguros. A pesar que el estándar C99 agregó dicha característica, es opcional que los compiladores los implemente, así que se pierde portabilidad y es propenso a que ocurra un stackoverflow. La forma correcta sería usar memoria dinámica (con malloc).

Comment: OH, no sabia que podía llevar a errores de desbordamiento si se declara un array así, gracias por compartir sus conocimientos.

Answer (score 1):

Los errores de compilación empiezan a partir de esta línea:

```c
if(alumno1[i].prom>mayor)
```

El identificador `alumno` no fue declarado como un *array*, por lo tanto, no puedes usar los corchetes para acceder a una determinada posición del *array*.

La **solución** es declarar el identificador `alumno` como un *array*.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
struct alumno{
char nombre[20];
char sexo[20];
int edad;
struct promedio prom;
}alumno1[50]; //--> ahora el identificador "alumnno1" si es un array
```

A pesar que esto debería de solucionar los problemas, el código sigue estando mal, porque en ningún momento tienes un campo en la estructura `alumno` donde guardes el promedio de cada estudiante. Esto servirá para calcular el mejor o pésimo promedio.

Un diseño de estructuras sería así:

```c
struct notas 
{
   float nota1;
   float nota2;
   float nota3;
};

struct alumno
{
   char nombre[20];
   char sexo[20];
   int edad;
   float promedio; //aquí podemos guardar el promedio
   struct notas notas;
}alumno1[50]; //La cantidad máxima serán 50 alumnos.
```

Entonces, la forma de pedir la información de cada estudiante sería:

```c
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n\nDigite su nombre: ");
    gets(alumno1[i].nombre);
    printf("Digite su sexo: ");
    gets(alumno1[i].sexo);
    printf("Digite su edad: ");
    scanf("%i",&alumno1[i].edad);
    printf("Digite las 3 notas: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f",&alumno1[i].notas.nota1,&alumno1[i].notas.nota2,&alumno1[i].notas.nota3);
    alumno[i].promedio = (alumno1[i].notas.nota1+alumno1[i].notas.nota2+alumno1[i].notas.nota3)/3;
    printf("\n\n-Datos del Alumno-\n");
    printf("\nNombre: %s",alumno1[i].nombre);
    printf("\nSexo: %s",alumno1[i].sexo);
    printf("\nEdad: %i",alumno1[i].edad);
    printf("\nPromedio: %.2f\n\n", alumno[i].promedio);
    fflush(stdin);
}
```

Y por último, para poder saber cual fue el mejor estudiante, se lo haría de esta forma:

```c
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    if(alumno1[i].promedio > mayor)
    {
        mayor = alumno1[i].promedio;
        pmay = i;
    }
    if(alumno1[i].promedio < menor)
    {
        menor = alumno1[i].promedio;
        pmen = i;
    }
}

printf("\n\n\n-Datos del alumno con Mejor promedio\n");
printf("\nSu nombre es:%s\n",alumno1[pmay].nombre);
printf("\nSu promedio es:%f\n",alumno1[pmay].promedio);
printf("\nSu edad es:%s\n",alumno1[pmay].edad);
printf("\nSu sexo es:%s\n",alumno1[pmay].sexo);
```

Como verás, los cambios son escasos, lo único que cambió, fue que le agregué un nuevo campo a la estructura `alumno`, de esto depende poder calcular el mayor promedio.

**Observación:**

En la solución propuesta usé un arreglo de estructura con almacenamiento estático, por ende, su tamaño es fijo, pero si el usuario ingresa un tamaño que sobrepasa la longitud máxima del arreglo, ocurrirá un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer). Así que se recomienda usar [memoria dinámica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoria_din%C3%A1mica_(programaci%C3%B3n)) o limitar la entrada al usuario para que no pueda sobrepasar el tamaño máximo del arreglo, sin embargo, esto hace que el programa quede limitado.